# Python 3, regex repetition and str.format() - what's the right way?

Tags: regex, string, python-3.x, format, repeat

I'd like to do regexp searches based on a variable's value.

In Py2.x this works very well:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"\b[a-zA-Z]{%(min_length)d,}\b" % locals())
```

When I try to port it to the new str.format() notation I get something like this:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"\b[a-zA-Z]{{0},}\b".format(min_length))
```

and this gives me an error as the braces from repetition get confused with the ones from str.format():

```
ValueError: Single '}' encountered in format string
```

I'm sure you can think of more examples like this where format() clashes with repetition.

What is the correct way to supply external value to regexp's repetition through str.format()? % operator does not work in Py3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the old version – `%` string formatting is still supported in Python 3.x, and it won't go away.  If you insist on using the new syntax, double the braces that are not indicating fields:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"\b[a-zA-Z]{{{0},}}\b".format(min_length))
```

Comment: Thanks. First I got syntax error with the % notation. Now it works fine ;) Thanks for the tip with double braces!